# how to solve forgot password when working on local but not working on heroku for devise in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, devise

I am using rails 4 and ruby 2. I have implemented login using devise. My problem is forgot password is not working on heroku but working on local. After receiving the mail when i clicked on "Change my password" link, it redirects to https://www.heroku.com/ page. How can I solve this issue? please help me if any one have any idea.

Codes:

reset_password_instructions.html.erb:

```
<p>Hello <%= @resource.email %>!</p>

<p>Someone has requested a link to change your password. You can do this through the link below.</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @resource.reset_password_token) %></p>

<p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
<p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>
```

Comment: To what url points the link in the email? It that url on the domain you expect it to be?

Comment: its pointing to heroku url. something like: http://www.herokuapp.com//bloggers/password/edit?reset_password_token=b6a939b31d73eege7fdea3e0d68467e69171a275a3a1454a31b9dd2345664734   and then redirect to https://www.heroku.com/  . and I am expecting other domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if you configured your server's url in your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'your.example.com' }
```

Find more details in the [Rails Guide about Mailers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#generating-urls-in-action-mailer-views).

Comment: Not working, I am getting mail, but when i clicked on "Change my password" it redirects to https://www.heroku.com/

Comment: How does the url in the email look like? How would you expect the url to look like? What is the difference between both versions?

Answer (score 1):

In you config/environments/production.rb file, you should have a looking like

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "http://eee.com" }
```

It defines the url used by action mailer when resolving url using the Rails url helpers. So If you set this value or change it, it should change the result.

Comment: Not working, I am getting mail, but when i clicked on "Change my password" it redirects to https://www.heroku.com/